# Bucket policy in Hive

Tags: hive

Can we create bucket on character field in Hive ?
example:

```sql
create table EmpTab(
    emp_id string,
    emp_name string,
    emp_city string,
    emp_grade char
);
```

Can I create bucket on emp_grade column ? If no then why ?

Comment: If my answer helped you, could you accept it as a correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You can use a coonstraction `CLUSTERED BY(emp_grade) INTO 5 BUCKETS` for that.

Example of a bucketed table creation:

```
CREATE TABLE user_info_bucketed(user_id BIGINT, firstname STRING, lastname STRING)
COMMENT 'A bucketed copy of user_info'
CLUSTERED BY(user_id) INTO 256 BUCKETS;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hive does not explicitly limit the data type of a column on which data is bucketed. And `char` is a legitimate type for bucketing.

You need to specify the bucketing column at table creation with `clustered by`.

```sql
 create table EmpTab(
    emp_id string,
    emp_name string,
    emp_city string,
    emp_grade char(10)
) clustered by (emp_grade) into 32 buckets
;
```

Note, `clustered by` on table creation does not restrict how data is inserted into the table.
To make sure that a bucketed table's data is organized in accordance with its DDL, enforce the number of reducers to be the same as the number of buckets.

Before 2.x, this can be done by simply setting `hive.enforce.bucketing` to be `true`.
Or you can manually set the number of reducers, and add a `cluster by` in the `select` clause.

After 2.x, the enforcement is defaulted and the conf `hive.enforce.bucketing` is [removed](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-12331).